# Developing and Distributing Portable and Cross-platform Ruby/JRuby Application

Tags: ruby, deployment, jruby, software-distribution

i was try to beginning ruby/jruby desktop application development, as i've googled before, ruby lacks of distribution/deployment system, so i haven't decided which one to use, is it ruby with green_shoes (gtk) or JRuby with purple_shoes (swing), if i go with green_shoes, then i should provide GTK Runtime, and if JRuby then i should provide JRE, or maybe if possible a portable internet browser and portable server (just like PHP's UniServer).

is there any other alternative to overcome this, so that i could distribute my program, ruby with all required dependency for my program only by copying the folder in such portable way?

so if i/they want to use it on windows, i only need to create a shortcut to the my program on the copied folder, 
and when i/they want to use it on linux, i only need to "ln -s" to $PATH to that my program on the copied folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for JRuby only:

- GUI toolkit, we can use Monkeybars https://github.com/monkeybars/monkeybars-core
- Deployment we can use rawr http://rawr.rubyforge.org/

answers from: Moh Hasbi Assidiqi